# Ordering of structures

Tags: c++, struct

I experience compile error when I try to do this

```
 struct Child{
    char Name[8];
    Parent *P;
 };

 struct Parent{
    char Name[8];
    Child *C;   
 };
```

The compiler complain it cannot find Parent in the `struct Child` but swapping their order did not help. The compiler will complain it cannot find a `Child` in `Parent`. How do I solve this error and why did error is not highlighted when I was write the program.

Comment: heh too late for answer.. but I have to add do not use Parent !!! if you on GUI app then Parent is usually reserved word for parent of window/app ...

Answer (score 6):

You can add the [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
struct Parent;   //forward declaration
struct Child{
    char Name[8];
    Parent *P;
};
```

Comment: just for the completeness, please note that, you wouldn't be able to do it in case if P was not a pointer to Parent but if it was an instance of Parent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare Parent before you can use it in struct Client:

```
struct Parent;

struct Child{
   char Name[8];
   Parent *P;
};

struct Parent{
   char Name[8];
   Child *C;   
};
```